# When URL changes on scroll to a certain hash, add a class to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, onscroll, hashchange

My URL hash changes **on scroll** from

- [www.website.com#section--1](http://www.website.com#section--1)
- [www.website.com#section--2](http://www.website.com#section--2)
- [www.website.com#section--3](http://www.website.com#section--3)

and so on. It's a fullpage-scrolling effect.

**What I want to do is to add the class .draw-shirt to the div #shirt when the URL changes on scroll to #section--2.**

I tried this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        if (window.location.href.indexOf("emotion--2") > -1) {
            $('#shirt').addClass('draw-shirt');
        }
    });
        
        

$(window).scroll(function () {
    
        function locationHashChanged() {
            if(window.location.href.indexOf("emotion--2") > -1) {
                $('#shirt').addClass('draw-shirt');
             }
        }

    });
```

It's working, if the URL is [www.website.com#section--2](http://www.website.com#section--2) on load but not on scroll.

The code

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {...etc...
```

is not working here because of the fullpage-scrolling-effect.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why is `locationHashChanged` a separate function in your `scroll()`? It never gets called by anything which is why your scroll version isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, in the code I mean section--2 of course, not emotion.

Comment: Have you tried using location.hash instead of location.href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use the [native](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) `hashchange` event of the window object.

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
    if (location.hash === '#emotion--2') {
        // your code to add class
   } 
});
```